# Embedding hidden encoded bits in plain text file

Tags: security, encryption, text, file-io, hash

I'm designing a system to process plain text files, one of its features will be to move processed files to an archive server once they've been completely processed through the system.  What I want to do is tag a text file once its been completely processed by the system, i.e. a system seal of approval or marker.  The reason for this is I want this same system to be able to analyze the text file later and search for this hidden marker so it can identify it as having been processed in the past.  At the same time, I want this marker to be ignored by any other system that might be handling this file

I was thinking of having a unique key that only this system uses and has access to and creating a procedure for hashing and salting the key and placing it within the text file before it gets moved to its final destination.  I'm curious about any other techniques for creating a hidden seal or marker.  So to summarize:

1. Can I create a set or string of encoded bits and place them in a text file?
2. Can these bits be hidden within the text file such that they are ignored by any other system that might handle this text file?

I'd appreciate any insight or feedback.

Comment: In your case, is it really OK to modify original content?

Comment: Instead of modifying the original content, it might be easier to use meta-data of the file system on the archive server. You could put a signature over the data in the meta-data. For instance, [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS#Metafiles) is a description of NTFS meta on wikipedia.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, i would avoid modifying original content, `ASCII text` file (to my knowledge) can't be signed in a way that would prevent all applications from seeing the signature.

Instead, i would take md5 of the file maintain "processed" one separately from the ones that have not yet been "processed.

`Map<MD5, FileName>` is a structure to consider. You should be able to write code to both retrieve by MD5 or file name.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Hiding data inside another file is called Steganography.  It can be done with ASCII files, but it is usually more easily done with data or image files.

In your particular case, a parallel register, or meta-data, of processed files would seem to be a better fit.  Using a good hash, MD5 or better, is fine as long as you do not expect malicious deliberate attacks.  In that case you would need to use HMAC-MD5 or HMAC-SHA-256.  A malicious attacker can easily calculate the correct hash value for the altered file.

Comment: Thanks for this insight rossum.